# Grails validation with composite key

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm running into a complex scenario where we are using a legacy database with composite keys and the client wants to be able alter two of the databases pks, "expenseDate" and "adjustmentNumber". In order to be able to change the pks, I've have to use a HQL query. Now of course this has caused another slew of issues with validation. My work around was to populate a domain so that I could validate against it.

So far everything works fine until we have a validation error that I'd like to return to the UI.

I have the following URL which uses the `recoveryDetail` controller and the `edit` action to render the page.

```
http://localhost:8080/pisr/recoveryDetail/edit?division=ALBANY&peid=PI0003&orgkey=14046701&expenseDate=07-22-2015&adjustmentNumber=1
```

**Edit action**

```
def edit() {
    //Parse clean url expense date
    params.expenseDate = new SimpleDateFormat('MM-dd-yyyy').parse(params.expenseDate)

    def recoveryDetailInstance = RecoveryDetail.get(new RecoveryDetail(params))

    if(recoveryDetailInstance == null) {
        redirect(uri:'/')
        return
    }

    [recoveryDetailInstance: recoveryDetailInstance, disabled: isdisabled(recoveryDetailInstance.batchOverride)]
}
```

And the following update action.

**Update action**

```
@Transactional
def update() {
    params.pk_expenseDate = getDateParser(params.pk_expenseDate)
    params.expenseDate = getDateParser(params.expenseDate)
    params.adjustmentNumber = getAdjustementNumber(params)

    RecoveryDetail recoveryDetailInstance = new RecoveryDetail(params);
    recoveryDetailInstance.division = params.pk_division
    recoveryDetailInstance.peid = params.pk_peid
    recoveryDetailInstance.orgkey = params.pk_orgkey

    recoveryDetailInstance .validate()

    if(recoveryDetailInstance .hasErrors()) {                       
        flash.message = "test"
        respond view: "edit", model:[recoveryDetailInstance:recoveryDetailInstance]
        return
    } else {
        def sqlParams = [
            pk_division:params.pk_division,
            pk_peid:params.pk_peid,
            pk_orgkey:params.pk_orgkey,
            pk_expenseDate:params.pk_expenseDate,
            pk_adjustmentNumber:params.int('pk_adjustmentNumber'),
            approved:YesNoTypes.valueOf(params.approved),
            batchOverride:YesNoTypes.valueOf(params.batchOverride),
            adjustmentFlag:params.adjustmentFlag,
            adjustmentNumber:params.adjustmentNumber,
            projectHours:new BigDecimal(params.projectHours),
            percentEffort:new BigDecimal(params.percentEffort),
            totalHours:new BigDecimal(params.totalHours),
            expenseDate:params.expenseDate
        ]

        RecoveryDetail.executeUpdate(recoveryDetailQuery, sqlParams)
    }
```

**Edit gsp**

```
            <g:form class="form-horizontal" url="[resource:recoveryDetailInstance, action:'update']" method="PUT">
                <!-- hidden fields contain params from url (composite key)-->
                <g:hiddenField name="pk_division" value="${recoveryDetailInstance?.division}"/>
                <g:hiddenField name="pk_peid" value="${recoveryDetailInstance?.peid}"/>
                <g:hiddenField name="pk_orgkey" value="${recoveryDetailInstance?.orgkey}"/>
                <g:hiddenField name="pk_expenseDate" value="${formatDate(format:'MM/dd/yyyy',date:recoveryDetailInstance?.expenseDate)}" />
                <g:hiddenField name="pk_adjustmentNumber" value="${recoveryDetailInstance?.adjustmentNumber}"/>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <g:render template="form" model="[recoveryDetailInstance: recoveryDetailInstance, 'mode':'edit']"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <g:actionSubmit class="btn btn-primary" action="update" disabled="${disabled}" value="${message(code: 'default.button.update.label', default: 'Update')}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </g:form>
```

**The problem**
When a user causes a validation error that triggers a server side response, I run into the following problems with the different return types.

**redirect** - this is returning the flash message, but redirects the gsp to the edit action which in turn fires the initializer query and replaces all the form data with the original data.

Example -

```
redirect (controller:"recoveryDetail", action:"edit", params:["division":params.pk_division, "peid":params.pk_peid, "orgkey": params.pk_orgkey, "expenseDate":params.expenseDate.format("MM-dd-yyyy"), "adjustmentNumber":params.adjustmentNumber])
```

respond - So I assumed I needed to just use respond, well it resulted in the following.

URL was changed to http://localhost:8080/pisr/recoveryDetail/update dropping all parameters and a 404 page was returned.

Example

```
flash.message = "test"
            respond view: "edit", model:[recoverDetailInstance:recoverDetailInstance]
            return
```

**So my question**

How do I throw a server side validation error and return it to the page with the data entered by the user?

Answer (score 0):

You may add the parameters back into the redirect or render call.

```
redirect (..., params: params)
```

https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html

Also, I'd suggest using a service instead of the controller method. Services are already transactional. I would also throw an exception if the `hasErrors` is true. The exception message or object can be your payload back to the user.

Comment: I did try the redirect call which is demonstrated in my question and it redirected back to the original edit action causing it to run the original query and replace all the data. I don't believe render will support params. I'll move everything into a service layer once I get things working.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Missed the params part.

Comment: So I think the solution was in fact render, but without the use of params. It just renders the update action.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use render without the use of params like so.

```
if(recoveryDetailInstance.hasErrors()) {
    render view: "edit", model:[recoveryDetailInstance:recoveryDetailInstance]
    return
}
```